DXF Importing error
I received this mess when trying to import a dxf file. How can I fix it?

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf_init_.py", line 521,
in execute
read(self.report, self.filepath, merge_options, self.import_text, self.import_light, self.export_acis,   File
"D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf_init_.py", line 98, in
read
do = Do(filename, obj_merge, import_text, import_light, export_acis, merge_lines, do_bbox, block_rep, recenter,   File
"D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfimport\do.py", line
86, in init
self.dwg = dxfgrabber.readfile(dxf_filename, {"assure_3d_coords": True})   File
"D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber_init_.py",
line 44, in readfile
return readfile_as_asc(filename, options)   File "D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber_init_.py",
line 59, in readfile_as_asc
return read_encoded_file(filename, options, encoding=get_encoding())   File
"D:\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_import_dxf\dxfgrabber_init.py",
line 55, in get_encoding
with io.open(filename) as fp: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'T:\01-Phong-Ban-XN\04-XN TK Ha Tang\12-Lê Thái Nam\Zalo
Recived Files\nut hang Dieu\'


There is likely something wrong with the DXF file, or it may be in a version that is not supported.

Thank @MartynasŽiemys i saved my file in 2018 format so let me try to save the CAD file to an older version
